# Evaluate Casbin policies real-time

Tags: mongodb, go, casbin

I use [Casbin](https://casbin.org/) as authorization library for my REST API, written in [Go](https://go.dev/).
To load the policy from my Mongo database, I use [MongoDB Adapter](https://github.com/casbin/mongodb-adapter).

A single policy Mongo document looks like this:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639491f73e4c9bec05a1d1ec"
  },
  "ptype": "p",
  "v0": "admin",
  "v1": "laptops",
  "v2": "read",
  "v3": "",
  "v4": "",
  "v5": ""
}
```

In my business logic, I validate if the user can access (read) laptops:

```golang
// Resolves to true
if can, _ := e.Enforce(user, "laptops", "read"); can {
    ...
```

This works fine.
The problem now is when I delete the policy document, I would expect that I'm not allowed to access laptops anymore. This is only the case when I restart my application.

Thus, it appears that the Enforce checks are not being evaluated real-time.

As a workaround, I could call the [LoadPolicy](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/casbin/casbin/v2#Enforcer.LoadPolicy) method as soon as the request comes in but this looks like a dirty hack to me.

I would really appreciate some help / suggestions.

Comment: Policies are obviously cached in memory so the implementation doesn't have to query the database every time (when the policies rarely change in the DB - performance!). After you modify the policies in the database, invalidate the cache.